Selenium BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
I am running several browsers in separate threads with help of selenium 4.2.0 (FireFox) and celery in docker container.
Program is working fine, but for significant amount of data I have an error (see trace below)
I read about the error https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1298/
Looks like it deals with breach of OS limit.
How to understand reason of the error and ways to fix it?
Traceback (most recent call last):
celery-1         |   File "/project/parser_app/celery_tasks.py", line 221, in check_urls
celery-1         |     parser = YandexParser()
celery-1         |   File "/project/parser_app/parser/common.py", line 195, in __init__
celery-1         |     self.driver = get_firefox_driver(proxy_data=proxy_data)
celery-1         |   File "/project/parser_app/parser/common.py", line 79, in get_firefox_driver
celery-1         |     driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxy_options, firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
celery-1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumwire/webdriver.py", line 179, in __init__
celery-1         |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
celery-1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 172, in __init__
celery-1         |     self.service.start()
celery-1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
celery-1         |     self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
celery-1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
celery-1         |     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
celery-1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1770, in _execute_child
celery-1         |     self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
celery-1         | BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable


I checked number of avaliable threads
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
4194304

Also checked number of zombie processes
ps aux | awk '$8 ~ /^[Zz]/' | wc -l
35990

And disk free space
~/new_app$ df -h --total
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G 1004K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       9.8G  3.3G  6.0G  36% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb        100G  5.1G   95G   6% /data
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1001
total           148G  8.4G  139G   6% -

